# Predicting rating of movie using other rating as input.

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am creating a collaborative filtering system for movie rating prediction. I am using this repository as a reference https://github.com/Piyushdharkar/Collaborative-Filtering-Using-Keras 
I want to implement something more into this. What I want is a function which can predict a rating of the last movie in a list given the rating of all other movies by a user. So the input is something like an array with rating as the element and with size `(1, no of movies-1)` and then I want output as a rating for the last movie. How can I do this?

Comment: There is no other input regarding the previous films and the current film, other than their rating score?

Comment: No, only ratings but they are going to be in the same sequence as per movie list in data. So if the first movie is Toy Story then the input vector will have a rating of Toy Story as the first element.

Comment: So to be clear, you want a model that gets a sequence of numbers and predicts the next number? without any context information?

Comment: No. You have to look at the repository link and then you will get what I am taking about. I have already replicated the codes in repo and can predict the rating given the ID of user and movie as input. But I want to predict the rating of last movie based on rating of other movies for a single user.